# Serial communication fails running outside IDE

Tags: java, netbeans, serial-port

I have one serial communication program which uses comm.jar libraries.
It absolutely works fine when run in Netbeans IDE.
But when I run its jar it fails to populate portList.
What is the reason behind this ? I have necessary files comm.jar in lib folder where the jar file exists.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you give us the error and show your code ?

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
    rcvd_data="";
    txt_data.setText(txt_data.getText()+"\nwrite()");
    portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
    txt_data.setText(txt_data.getText()+"\n"+portList.hasMoreElements());//getting false here when running it putside from IDE
    while (portList.hasMoreElements()) 
    {
        txt_data.setText(txt_data.getText()+"\nwhile()");
        portId = (CommPortIdentifier)portList.nextElement();

        if(portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL)
        {
            if(portId.getName().equals("COM2"))
            {
                try{
                    writeToSerial();
                    rcvd_data = readFromSerial();
                    txt_data.setText(txt_data.getText()+"\nData:"+rcvd_data);
                    serialPort.removeEventListener();
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println(""+e);
                    txt_data.setText(""+e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }    
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(""+e.getMessage());
    }
```